# Find consecutive records with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a query to find consecutive 2 `period`s for each `site` which `utilization_rate` is smaller than `50`.

Table:

```
ID Name    Period   Utilization_Rate
------------------------------------
1  Site 1  2014-R1  40
2  Site 1  2014-R2  30 
3  Site 1  2014-R3  25
4  Site 2  2014-R1  30
5  Site 2  2014-R2  20
6  Site 2  2014-R2  60
7  Site 3  2014-R2  30
8  Site 3  2014-R2  70
9  Site 3  2014-R2  40
```

Expected result:

```
ID Name    Period   Utilization_Rate
------------------------------------
1  Site 1  2014-R1  40
2  Site 1  2014-R2  30 
3  Site 1  2014-R3  25
4  Site 2  2014-R1  30
5  Site 2  2014-R2  20
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How are you getting the expected results?  For instance, why is id "3" in the list but not id "9"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think "3" is included because it follows "2" and utilization < 50 on both. Row "9" is not in the list because row "8" is not in the list, which is it's neighbour in the original data. The same reason that "5" and "7" are out (because of "6" not qualifying).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `OUTER APPLY` version of Gordon's answer:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c376/2/0)

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE 
        Name = t.Name
        AND ID < t.ID
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)p
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE
        Name = t.Name
        AND Id > t.ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC
)n
WHERE
    t.Utilization_Rate < 50
    AND (p.Utilization_Rate < 50 OR n.Utilization_Rate < 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and give me the correct answer. How do I edit the query to find more than 2 consecutive periods

Answer (score 1):

I think you want all pairs of rows (based on the period and site) where both utilization rates are less than 50.

If so, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(utilization_rate) over (partition by name order by period) as prev_ur,
             lead(utilization_rate) over (partition by name order by period) as next_ur,
      from tbl t
     ) t
where utilization_rate < 50 and (prev_ur < 50 or next_ur < 50);
```

These functions are available in SQL Server 2012+.  If you are using an earlier version, you can do something similar with correlated subqueries or `outer apply`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c376/1/0)

Comment: You don't need to partition by `period`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan . . . Thank you for that observation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and give me the correct answer. How do I edit the query to find more than 2 consecutive periods

Comment: @Tony . . . This question is quite explicitly about two periods. More periods is a different question.  Please include sample data and desired results.  That said, it might just be a simple matter of adding more `lag()` and `lead()` values to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Same query using plain old joins

```
select t.* from 
tbl t 
left join tbl tp on t.id-1=tp.id and t.name=tp.name
left join tbl tn on t.id+1=tn.id and t.name=tn.name
where t.utilization_rate < 50 and 
( 
  ISNULL(tp.utilization_rate,0) < 50 or ISNULL(tn.utilization_rate,0) < 50
)
```

Comment: The problem here is if there's a gap on `id`s, your query might fail.